# after we connact MS Access database with C#, How to Move our system from a computer to another Computer?

Tags: c#

my code is for connection :

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\mohamed.rifkan\Documents\Database2.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";

Answer (score 0):

You just edit the path in the Source part of your connection string there to the new location.

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(); connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=**C:\Users\mohamed.rifkan\Documents**\Database2.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";

Change the bold part to the new path. If this is not the answer, then I do not understand the question properly.

Comment: i can not understand , can you please expalain me or if you send me a video tutorial for this it will be more helpful, please